# Job invalid: `selector` not auto-generated

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I have kubectl job that is invalid. I am debugging it and I extracted it to yaml file and I can see this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2020-03-19T21:40:11Z
  labels:
    app: vault-unseal-app
    job-name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
  name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
  namespace: infrastructure
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: CronJob
    name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
    uid: c9965fdb-4fbb-11e9-80d7-061cf1426d5a
  resourceVersion: "163413544"
  selfLink: /apis/batch/v1/namespaces/infrastructure/jobs/vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
  uid: 35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vault-unseal-app
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: vault-unseal-app
        job-name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: VAULT_ADDR
          value: http://vault-vault:8200
        - name: VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY
          value: "1"
        - name: VAULT_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: vault_token
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_0
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_0
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_1
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_1
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_2
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_2
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_3
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_3
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_4
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_4
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        image: blockloop/vault-unseal
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: vault-unseal
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        nodePool: ci
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: 2020-03-19T21:49:11Z
    lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-19T21:49:11Z
    message: Job has reached the specified backoff limit
    reason: BackoffLimitExceeded
    status: "True"
    type: Failed
  failed: 1
  startTime: 2020-03-19T21:40:11Z
```

When I run `kubectl create -f my_file.yaml`, I am getting this error:

```
The Job "vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"controller-uid":"35262878-07bb-11eb-9b2c-0abca2a23428", "app":"vault-unseal-app"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: `selector` not auto-generated
```

Can someone suggest how to fix this?

Update:

After testing removal of `.spec.selector` I am getting error: `error: jobs.batch "vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000" is invalid`

This is how my config looks without `.spec.selector`:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"batch/v1","kind":"Job","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2020-03-19T21:40:11Z","labels":{"controller-uid":"35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4","job-name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000"},"name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000","namespace":"infrastructure","ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"batch/v1beta1","blockOwnerDeletion":true,"controller":true,"kind":"CronJob","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal","uid":"c9965fdb-4fbb-11e9-80d7-061cf1426d5a"}],"resourceVersion":"163427805","selfLink":"/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/infrastructure/jobs/vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000","uid":"35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4"},"spec":{"backoffLimit":20,"completions":1,"parallelism":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"controller-uid":"35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4"}},"template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"controller-uid":"35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4","job-name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"VAULT_ADDR","value":"http://vault-vault:8200"},{"name":"VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY","value":"1"},{"name":"VAULT_TOKEN","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"vault_token","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal"}}},{"name":"VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_0","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"unseal_key_0","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal"}}},{"name":"VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_1","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"unseal_key_1","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal"}}},{"name":"VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_2","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"unseal_key_2","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal"}}},{"name":"VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_3","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"unseal_key_3","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal"}}},{"name":"VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_4","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"unseal_key_4","name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal"}}}],"image":"blockloop/vault-unseal","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"vault-unseal","resources":{},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File"}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","nodeSelector":{"nodePool":"devs"},"restartPolicy":"OnFailure","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{},"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":5}}},"status":{"conditions":[{"lastProbeTime":"2020-03-19T21:49:11Z","lastTransitionTime":"2020-03-19T21:49:11Z","message":"Job has reached the specified backoff limit","reason":"BackoffLimitExceeded","status":"True","type":"Failed"}],"failed":1,"startTime":"2020-03-19T21:40:11Z"}}
  creationTimestamp: 2020-03-19T21:40:11Z
  labels:
    controller-uid: 35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4
    job-name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
  name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
  namespace: infrastructure
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: CronJob
    name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
    uid: c9965fdb-4fbb-11e9-80d7-061cf1426d5a
  resourceVersion: "163442526"
  selfLink: /apis/batch/v1/namespaces/infrastructure/jobs/vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
  uid: 35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4
spec:
  backoffLimit: 100
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        controller-uid: 35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4
        job-name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: VAULT_ADDR
          value: http://vault-vault:8200
        - name: VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY
          value: "1"
        - name: VAULT_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: vault_token
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_0
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_0
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_1
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_1
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_2
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_2
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_3
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_3
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        - name: VAULT_UNSEAL_KEY_4
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: unseal_key_4
              name: vault-unseal-vault-unseal
        image: blockloop/vault-unseal
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: vault-unseal
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        nodePool: devs
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: 2020-03-19T21:49:11Z
    lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-19T21:49:11Z
    message: Job has reached the specified backoff limit
    reason: BackoffLimitExceeded
    status: "True"
    type: Failed
  failed: 1
  startTime: 2020-03-19T21:40:11Z
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are not using the `selector` that the system generates for you automatically by default. Bear in mind that the recommended option when creating a job is NOT to fill in `selector`. It makes it more probable to create a duplicate labels+selectors. Therefore you should use the auto-generated ones, which ensure uniqueness and release you from the necessity of manual management.

The [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#specifying-your-own-pod-selector) have this explained in more detail with an example. Please notice the below parts:

> Normally, when you create a Job object, you do not specify
> `.spec.selector`. The system defaulting logic adds this field when the
> Job is created. It picks a selector value that will not overlap with
> any other jobs.

and:

> You need to specify `manualSelector: true` in the new Job since you
> are not using the selector that the system normally generates for you
> automatically.

If you want to use manual selectors you need to set: `.spec.manualSelector: true` in the job's spec. This way the API server will not generate labels automatically and you will be able to set them yourself.

EDIT:

Remember that `spec.Completions` `spec.Selector` and `spec.Template` are immutable fields and are not allowed to be updated. In order to make changes there you need to create a new Job.

The official docs regarding [Writing a Job spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#writing-a-job-spec) will help you understand what should and what shouldn't be put into the Job spec. Notice that despite:

> In addition to required fields for a Pod, a pod template in a Job must
> specify appropriate labels (see [pod selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-selector)) and an appropriate
> restart policy.

it is advised that the pod selector / labels are not specified as I explained earlier in order to not create a duplicate labels+selectors.

Comment: How would you adjust this job to use the default selector? Is it enough if I just remove the  .spec.selector from the definition and apply that file?

Comment: Correct, all you need to do is do not specify `.spec.selector`.

Comment: When I try to remove `.spec.selector`, it says that my yaml file is invalid. I will update my question with new configuration

Comment: What is the full error message? Have you tried to edit the yaml or create a brand-new one but without the ` .spec.selector` field?

Comment: I have tried to create a new one without `.spec.selector`, and it looks:
```
The Job "vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000" is invalid: 
* spec.template.metadata.labels[controller-uid]: Invalid value: map[string]string{"controller-uid":"35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4", "job-name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000"}: must be '0f360aba-07d8-11eb-9b2c-0abca2a23428'
* spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"controller-uid":"35e63c20-6a2a-11ea-b577-069afd6d30d4", "job-name":"vault-unseal-vault-unseal-1584654000"}: `selector` does not match template `labels````

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. You shouldn't use labels either. They are going to be assigned automatically. [Writing a Job spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#writing-a-job-spec) will explain that in more detail. Simply create a Job without labels and selectors and see how they get it assigned automatically with: `kubectl describe jobs/job_name`.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor good piece of reference for the job specs, my question would be how would you make a network policy selector for these jobs pods, as I found it to be not possible to do that without proper selectors that are set manually

Comment: @Waheed Glad you found it useful. For your next question I think it would be better to explain the while use case in a form of a new Stack question. It would be more clear and visible for the rest of the community to do it that way instead of analyzing it in the comments.

Comment: my question is here as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478086/kubernetes-cronjob-labeling